# Value on the database increments/decrements automatically after each operation

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, sql-server-2008, model-view-controller

currently I'm doing a simple project where user enters his family details and saves that details to database.And he can generate PDF by using these values,
I have given an option to edit or add member details before creating the PDF's.
the code is given below

**code to insert values in to DB:**

```
var connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["KMDContext"].ConnectionString;
                    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connString);
                    con.Open();
                    string DeleteFamily = "DELETE  FROM family WHERE UserProfileID='" + Convert.ToInt32(Session["UserId"].ToString()) + "' ";
                    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmdFamilyDelete = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(DeleteFamily, con);
                    cmdFamilyDelete.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    if (Family != null)
                    {

                        DateTime DOB = DateTime.Now;
                        for (int i = 0; i < Family.Count; i++)
                        {
                            int Age = Convert.ToInt32(Family[i].Age);
                            DOB = DOB.AddYears(-(Age));
                            string InsertFamily = "INSERT INTO family (UserProfileID ,Name,Relation,DOB,Job) VALUES('" + Convert.ToInt32(Session["UserId"].ToString()) + "','" + Family[i].Name + "','" + Family[i].Relation + "','" + DOB + "','" + Family[i].Job + "')";
                            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(InsertFamily, con);
                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }

                    }
```

The age calculation is done by using javascript

```
var dob = new Date(element.DateOFBirth);
var today = new Date();
var age = (today.getFullYear() - dob.getFullYear());
```

user have to enter the age of his family members and i need to save the date of birth(approximate value) to the database.

***My issue***

After each generation of PDF an entirely different value for age is saving to the database.(an user saves a family member with age **27** for the first time, after generating a PDF,this value automatically changes to **37**.sometime it goes to -ve values)

is there anything wrong in the code?

what is the exact reason for the issue?

Comment: You should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/) by the way. This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. Also based on their names, some of your columns should be a numeric type instead of character.

Comment: Just store the users date of birth. Sheesh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set `DateTime DOB = DateTime.Now;` inside the for loop. Or else it will calculate the wrong value when you have more than one person in the family.

Say person 1 is 10 years old and person 2 20 years old. Person 1: DOB will be 2016-10=2006. Person 2: DOB will be 2006-20=1986.